# KnockoutJS - How to update observable value generically

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0, ko.observablearray

I have a 3rd party custom jquery component that overrides a checkbox and provides a prettier "toggle"  look for it.  The component has a function callback that occurs whenever the user clicks the component.

How do I set the observable value using the event target without knowing specifically which property in my view model the event is being called for.

For example:

Html is:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cb123" data-bind="checked: IsDeleted" />
<input type="checkbox" id="cb345" data-bind="checked: IsValid" />
```

Javascript callback is like the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     .... Code snipped  ....
     var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(myModel);
     ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

      $(':checkbox').toggleCheckbox({
           onChange: function($el, value, e) {
              var ctx = ko.contextFor(e.target);    // Gets me the knockout context object.

              // How do I set the appropriate observable value from here?
              // In this case either one of the checkboxes could have been triggered.
           }
      });
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hey and welcome to SO. I'm just starting to work with knockout myself so I'm not quite sure but you may be able to use a computed observable (to pull the value from the checkbox and run any checks if needed) and then have it subscribe to the checkbox(s). Just a thought.

Answer (score 1):

One way to get an observable is to parse data-bind attribute itself:

```
// inside your event handler
var viewModel = ko.dataFor(e.target);
var bindValue = $(e.target).data('bind');
// in case you applied 'checked' binding only: data-bind="checked: IsDeleted"
var observableName = $.trim(bindValue.split(':')[1]);

// get value
var _value = viewModel[observableName]();
// set value: viewModel[observableName](newValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a custom bindingHandler to initialize the toggleCheckbox.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cb123" data-bind="toggleCheckboxChecked: IsDeleted" />
<input type="checkbox" id="cb345" data-bind="toggleCheckboxChecked: IsValid" />
```

Javascript:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.toggleCheckboxChecked = {
   init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
       // This is just to set the initial value of the checkbox
       element.checked = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());

       // Then turn the element into an enhanced checkbox
       $(element).toggleCheckbox({
           onChange: function($el, value, e) {
              var checkedBinding = valueAccessor();
              checkedBinding(value);
           }
       });
   },
   update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
       // this is invoked by knockout when checkedBinding changes, so
       // to get a two-way-binding you need to update the checkbox component
       // here with ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor())
   }
}
```

There is some information about custom binding handlers on the [official page](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html), but I also recommend rniemeyer's blog, in particular [this post](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/07/another-look-at-custom-bindings-for.html).